# facing issue of captcha while login to google after entered mail using playwright pytest in headless mode

Tags: authentication, captcha, playwright-python

I am using pytest-playwright to automate Google/Gmail acccount
playwright version:  ~=1.37.0

After entering email click on next then ask to enter text which you see a captcha.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znmwJ.png)

set the userAgent property for a page in Playwright with pytest using the Playwright context